# How to open a closed diagram in Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I accidentally closed a diagram in Papyrus editor. I just clicked the close button in diagram tab in model.di file. Now I cannot get it back and my sequence diagram is lost. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear: you closed the diagram (editor) from its tab at the bottom of the editor pane and not the tab with the ".di" file.

If so, don't worry, the content is still available in the model. Just lookin the Model explorer (typically on the left of the Eclipse workbench) for the diagram and re-open it. If your model is large, you can see only the diagrams by clicking on the model explorer's lefmost toolbar button (it looks like 3 lines of "bullet dash").

If the model explorer is not shown, simply type "model explorer" in the "Quick Access" box at the top left of the workbench to open it.

If you did close the model itself (the ".di" tab at the top), you should have been prompted if the model was dirty and needed saving. If you did get the prompt and did not save, you may have lost your work. Depending on how long you have worked on your model, you may have something saved in "local history", which can be accessed by right-clicking on the model in the project explorer and selecting "Team > Local History".
I hope this helps.